# US international keyboard on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and would like to type French/Portuguese accents with a US keyboard. I just cannot find the US International keyboard that existed on Ubuntu 18.04.

Anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: The name of the layout I use is 'English (intl. with AltGr dead keys)'. Is that available? (I stick with Lubuntu 18.04 for the moment.) It's in 20.04, [here is a screenshot](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1600275652.png).

Comment: Nope, I cannot see this option.. see the [screenshot](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1600277343.png)

Comment: Got it now.. It's not that intuitive, but it appears after I double-clicked on English US row. Working like a charm now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed. It could be more intuitive. If you get time, you could write up the answer with details and accept it as an answer. That way, someone else can find it and learn. If not, I can write up an answer with screenshots - but I can't do that until later today. I have to run out for a couple of hours.

Comment: @KGIII Suggested and done. Thank you!

Comment: You can even accept your own answer. I threw you a vote, but you can accept your answer as well. Congratulations and thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

US International with dead keys is out there, but as stated previously, itś not very intuitive to find.

First step, go to *Settings -> Region & Language* and then click on **+** sign of *Input Sources*
[image: First step]

After double-click *English (United States)*
[image: second step]

and voilà!
[image: US, Intl., with dead keys]

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: why ubuntu... why complicate that which was not... also thanks for sharing, saved my day

Comment: Ubuntu definetly need to change this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you found an easy way of using ç with this layout?