# US International Keyboard on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I can't figure out how to select the English International Keyboard with dead keys on Ubuntu Kinetic.

This questions has been answered for older releases of Ubuntu ([18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045352/us-international-keyboard-with-dead-keys-ubuntu-18-04) [20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275597/us-international-keyboard-on-ubuntu-20-04)).

When following the 20.04 instruction, I don't see the US International Keyboard with dead keys available:

[image: English Options]

Comment: Apart from the fact that 21.10 is unsupported, what happens if you select "English (United States)"? It should offer you a bunch of alternatives, including the one you are looking for. @guiverc: This GNOME design issue is there on all recent releases.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks, that fixed it! I didn't realize that there is a sub-menu under "English (United States)". If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it so future users don't have to read the comments.

Comment: Please feel free to formulate an answer yourself. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

To add the US international keyboard, one must click on the `English (United States)` in the menu above, which provides a sub-menu that contains the desired keyboard layout:

*Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources ->* **+** *-> English (United States) -> English (US, intl., with dead keys)*

Note that selecting a second layout enables a new icon on the gnome desktop taskbar, which may be used to select your keyboard. Alternatively the default keybind `super + spacebar` will switch layouts.